# How to parse and update jenkins job config.xml using python jenkinsapi module

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

I have installed Jenkinsapi python module and created below python script.

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
jenkinsSource = 'http://10.52.123.124:8080/'
server = Jenkins(jenkinsSource, username = 'XXXXX', password = 'YYYYY')
myJob=server.get_job("__test")
myConfig=myJob.get_config()
print myConfig
```

Now I need to parse the XML from the variable `myConfig` and fetch the value given for triggers (cron entry) and save it to another variable in python. So that I can replace the cron entry using jenkinsapi module.

Answer (score 2):

You can read `myConfig` with xpath, see code below which reads `numToKeep` from `hudson.tasks.LogRotator`. This prints out jobs whose build retention is set to more than 10 in *Discard old builds* job configuration.

Calling code

```
jobs = server.get_jobs()

for job in jobs:
    full_name = job['fullname']
    config = server.get_job_config(full_name)
    num_days = h.get_value_from_string(config, key='.//numToKeep')
    if num_days > 10:
        print(full_name, num_days)
```

Helper function which reads property from config

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_value_from_string(xml_string, key):
    parsed = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
    find_result = parsed.findall(key)

    value = 0
    if len(find_result) > 0:
        value = int(find_result[0].text)

    return value
```

To update a jobs configuration

```
config = server.get_job_config('<the_job>')
old_config_part = '<numToKeep>100</numToKeep>'
new_config_part = '<numToKeep>5</numToKeep>'
new_config = config.replace(old_config_part, new_config_part)
server.reconfig_job(full_name, new_config)
```